# Pellet owl api 2.4.0 and java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyDomain

Tags: nosuchmethoderror, owl-api, pellet, reasoner

Using pellet-2.4.0, Getting the same error on running my application:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLObjectPropertyDomainAxiom.getProperty()Lorg/semanticweb/owlapi/model/OWLPropertyExpression

Have tried printing classpath, but am unable to find any discrepancy,

Please help,

My classpath as printed in my application is:
        E:\Pallavi\NetbeansProjects\SemanticCoverage\target\classes;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\google\inject\guice\4.1.0\guice-4.1.0.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\19.0\guava-19.0.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-multibindings\4.0\guice-multibindings-4.0.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\owlapi-fixers\5.0.1\owlapi-fixers-5.0.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sf\trove4j\trove4j\3.0.3\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\github\ben-manes\caffeine\caffeine\2.1.0\caffeine-2.1.0.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\google\inject\extensions\guice-assistedinject\4.0\guice-assistedinject-4.0.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\2.0.1\jsr305-2.0.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.14\slf4j-api-1.7.14.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\2.4\commons-io-2.4.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\owlapi-api\5.0.5\owlapi-api-5.0.5.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\tukaani\xz\1.5\xz-1.5.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-rdf-api\0.1.0-incubating\commons-rdf-api-0.1.0-incubating.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.7.24\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.24.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\owlapi-osgidistribution\5.0.5\owlapi-osgidistribution-5.0.5.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.6.3\jackson-core-2.6.3.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.6.3\jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.6.3\jackson-annotations-2.6.3.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-model\4.0.2\sesame-model-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-api\4.0.2\sesame-rio-api-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-languages\4.0.2\sesame-rio-languages-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-datatypes\4.0.2\sesame-rio-datatypes-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-binary\4.0.2\sesame-rio-binary-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-n3\4.0.2\sesame-rio-n3-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-nquads\4.0.2\sesame-rio-nquads-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-ntriples\4.0.2\sesame-rio-ntriples-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-rdfjson\4.0.2\sesame-rio-rdfjson-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-rdfxml\4.0.2\sesame-rio-rdfxml-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-trix\4.0.2\sesame-rio-trix-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-turtle\4.0.2\sesame-rio-turtle-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-rio-trig\4.0.2\sesame-rio-trig-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\openrdf\sesame\sesame-util\4.0.2\sesame-util-4.0.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\github\jsonld-java\jsonld-java\0.8.0\jsonld-java-0.8.0.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient-osgi\4.5.1\httpclient-osgi-4.5.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpmime\4.5.1\httpmime-4.5.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\fluent-hc\4.5.1\fluent-hc-4.5.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore-osgi\4.4.4\httpcore-osgi-4.4.4.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore-nio\4.4.4\httpcore-nio-4.4.4.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.7.13\jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.1\httpclient-4.5.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient-cache\4.5.1\httpclient-cache-4.5.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.4\httpcore-4.4.4.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.10\commons-codec-1.10.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\semarglproject\semargl-sesame\0.6.1\semargl-sesame-0.6.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\semarglproject\semargl-core\0.6.1\semargl-core-0.6.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\semarglproject\semargl-rdfa\0.6.1\semargl-rdfa-0.6.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\semarglproject\semargl-rdf\0.6.1\semargl-rdf-0.6.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\servicemix\bundles\org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject\1_2\org.apache.servicemix.bundles.javax-inject-1_2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\servicemix\bundles\org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance\1.0_6\org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aopalliance-1.0_6.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\org.semanticweb.hermit\1.3.8.510\org.semanticweb.hermit-1.3.8.510.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-api\1.2.14\axiom-api-1.2.14.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec\1.1\geronimo-activation_1.1_spec-1.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec\1.7.1\geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.7.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\jaxen\jaxen\1.1.4\jaxen-1.1.4.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\geronimo\specs\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec\1.0.1\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\james\apache-mime4j-core\0.7.2\apache-mime4j-core-0.7.2.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-c14n\1.2.14\axiom-c14n-1.2.14.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-impl\1.2.14\axiom-impl-1.2.14.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\woodstox-core-asl\4.1.4\woodstox-core-asl-4.1.4.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\codehaus\woodstox\stax2-api\3.1.1\stax2-api-3.1.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\ws\commons\axiom\axiom-dom\1.2.14\axiom-dom-1.2.14.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\dk\brics\automaton\automaton\1.11-8\automaton-1.11-8.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\pellet-owlapi-ignazio1977\2.4.0-ignazio1977\pellet-owlapi-ignazio1977-2.4.0-ignazio1977.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\pellet-core-ignazio1977\2.4.0-ignazio1977\pellet-core-ignazio1977-2.4.0-ignazio1977.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\github\ansell\aterms\aterm-java\1.8.2-p1\aterm-java-1.8.2-p1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\github\ansell\jjtraveler\jjtraveler\0.6\jjtraveler-0.6.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\github\ansell\aterms\shared-objects\1.4.9-p1\shared-objects-1.4.9-p1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\jgrapht\jgrapht-jdk1.5\0.7.3\jgrapht-jdk1.5-0.7.3.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\xerces\xercesImpl\2.11.0\xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.4.01\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\jena\jena-arq\2.10.1\jena-arq-2.10.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\jena\jena-core\2.10.1\jena-core-2.10.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\apache\jena\jena-iri\0.9.6\jena-iri-0.9.6.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\pellet-query-ignazio1977\2.4.0-ignazio1977\pellet-query-ignazio1977-2.4.0-ignazio1977.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\pellet-jena-ignazio1977\2.4.0-ignazio1977\pellet-jena-ignazio1977-2.4.0-ignazio1977.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.4\antlr-runtime-3.4.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\org\antlr\stringtemplate\3.2.1\stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.7\antlr-2.7.7.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\net\sourceforge\owlapi\owlapi-distribution\4.1.4\owlapi-distribution-4.1.4.jar;
    C:\Users\DrKM.m2\repository\com\github\jsonld-java\jsonld-java-sesame\0.5.0\jsonld-java-sesame-0.5.0.jar

Answer (score 1):

You have OWLAPI 4 and OWLAPI 5 in the classpath; That fork of Pellet is not compatible with OWLAPI 5.

If you're using OWLAPI 5, use Openllet instead

https://github.com/Galigator/openllet